# How can I add a close button to a html video popup?

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

I have an image on my site, and when you click on the image, a video pops up and starts playing. I am wondering how I can add a close button on this video to go back to website rather than pressing back.

I'm pretty experienced with HTML CSS but very new to JS.

This is the code that causes the popup video.

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <a href="assets/video.mp4">
    <img src="assets/img.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: share complete popup html with css or share a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that, you add all the code. HTML/CSS/JS and so, we can help you.

I recommend that, a snippet, that stackoverflow eases you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqoA3.png)

The snippet is:
[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sg9M.png)

If you are new in JS. I recommend work with the framework jQuery.